# Use a generating function to count the number of combinations of two quarters, five dimes, and ten nickels that have total value of $75$¢ and $\$1.00$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

The answers given in my book are $12, 10$ respectively.

I consider the function $(1 + Y^5 + Y^{10})(1 + Y^2 + Y^4 + Y^6 + Y^8 + Y^{10})(1 + Y + Y^2 + \ldots + Y^{10})$ where $Y$ stands for a $5$-cent unit.

I use synthetic multiplication to multiply through the polynomials.

Wasn't able to get  the numbers perfectly aligned. So,

$1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1\\
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 \\
– - - - - -  \\
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 \\ \quad
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 \\  \qquad
        1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 \\  \quad \quad \quad
            1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 \\  \quad \quad \quad \quad
                1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 \\  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
                    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 \\  
– - - - - - - - - - - \\
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1$

and

$1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 \\
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 \\
– - - - - - \\
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 \\ \quad \qquad
          1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 \\ \qquad \quad \quad \quad
                    1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 \\
– - - - - - - - - - -  \\
1\ 1 \ 2 \  2 \ 3 \ 4 \ 5 \ 6 \ 7 \ 8 \ 10 \ 10 \ 11 \ 11 \ 12 \ \color{red}{\fbox {12}} \ 12 \ 11 \ 11 \ 10 \ \color{blue}{\fbox 9} \ 8 \ 7 \ 6 \ 5 \ 3 \ 3 \ 2 \ 2 \ 1$

So my answers are $12, 9.$

Are my calculations correct? If they are not, what can I do to fix the whole thing? Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the result should be symmetric - the number of ways to get $n$ cents should be the same as the number of ways to get $150-n$ cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer---as Thomas Andrews points out---should be symmetric, and indeed it looks like you forgot a $1$ at the end of your first synthetic multiplication.